# Internet Explorer 7-10 delete Content-Length in xhr/activex

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem that's very similar to the following:
[IE's XMLhttpRequest's getResponseHeader("Content-Length") absent when Content-Encoded sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688871/ies-xmlhttprequests-getresponseheadercontent-length-absent-when-content-en)

I'm trying to get the filesize of a specific JS-File, it looks like this:

```
var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
if (!req) {
    throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');
}
req.open('HEAD', urlToScript, false);
req.send(null);
var size = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
```

The size variable is an empty string in ie < 10, and `null` in ie 10. The code works perfectly fine on other browsers like FF or Chrome.

This problem seems to occur only if the content requested is gzipped.

In IE, the headers are missing 'Content-Length' and 'Content-Encoding' if I print them with `req.getAllResponseHeaders()`:

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Mar 2010 07:01:40 GMT
Expires: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 12:03:27 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 12:03:26 GMT
```

where Firefox 20 prints much more information:

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Mar 2010 07:01:40 GMT
Expires: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 12:05:24 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17669
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 12:05:24 GMT
X-Cache: MISS from somewhere.com
Via: 1.1 somewhere.com:8001 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

I also tried to set the 'Content-Type' to 'application/javascript' and manually set 'Accept-Encoding' request headers. Nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a cross domain HTTP request?